# Firebase - unique references across lists

Tags: firebase, angularfire

When creating a new firebase reference using $add() in angularFire it returns a unique reference. Is the uniqueness just within the parent list or is it unique across all lists?

Reason I ask is I seem to have ended up with a duplicate reference in two unassociated lists that I am looking to merge, I cannot merge as the duplicate reference merges two records that should remain separate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$add` function internally calls [Firebase.push()](https://www.firebase.com/docs/javascript/firebase/push.html), which is unique across all paths for a given Firebase instance. These are timestamp-based UUIDs that sort chronologically, and are semi-impossible to obtain a duplicate.

If there are duplicate references in two unassociated lists, then there is more at play here and code that reproduces the error would be necessary to delve any further into the problem.

Comment: Thanks, i've looked through my code and there is nothing obvious that could have caused this. That said it is one of the very first entries in the now considerably long list and there have been several releases of code since. It may have been an early bug that has since been inadvertently fixed. Will monitor and revert if I see it happen again.

Comment: I am developing a Firebase-based app, and we rely on the global uniqueness property: "... is unique across all paths for a given Firebase instance."  But we couldn't find it in the documentation.  If you have, could you please give me some pointers on it?